# What are the alternative's to using the iThenticate service for content comparison?

Tags: search, drm, plagiarism-detection

What are the alternative's to using the [iThenticate](http://www.ithenticate.com) service for content comparison?

Answer (score 2):

Wikipedia page on [plagiarism detection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plagiarism_detection) has a list of commercial and free services.

Answer (score 1):

I generally recommend [Copyscape](http://www.copyscape.com) and/or [eTBlast](http://etest.vbi.vt.edu/etblast3/) if you choose not to use iThenticate.